# VLC player in ViewPager

Tags: android, surfaceview, libvlc

I am using VLC lib for video buffering online. and I have used ViewPager from playing multiple online video. My problem is that current page video is not played but next video is played. How to achieve this.

Comment: check the position from your arraylist

Comment: I have checked every thing ok, I am getting problem because viewpager load two page in starting.

Comment: you should show your implementation, it will help better to find out your problem